# How to php regular expression get the final part of the url?

Tags: php, regex

HI, if there have many url address.

```
http://www.aaa.com/dd/cc/ee
http://www.bbb.com/ff/gg
http://www.ccc.com/hh/jj/kk/ll
```

how to use php regular expression to get the final part of the url? 
`ee`,
`gg`,
`ll`

Comment: The url can have query parameters? Can it be finished by a `/` (ie : _http:// www.bbb.com/ff/gg/_)? More precision and thinking ahead of a problem is the key.

Answer (score 6):

It might be easier to use `basename()` instead of a regex:

```
basename('http://www.ccc.com/hh/jj/kk/ll', '/');
```

Comment: PHP is chock full of these little solutions. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Only issue with that is it does not account for query parameters...  (so `hh/jj/kk/ll?foo/bar` will return `bar` instead of `ll`)...  (or depending on what the needs are, `ll?foo/bar`)...

Comment: might want to make that basename($url, '/'); since trailing slashes can easily be added to urls by browsers/users; you need to drop the trailing slash off.

Comment: @threendib, good call.  Added.  There's also `parse_url()` if you need to separate the path from the query.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use regular expressions?  Why not use [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/parse_url)

```
function getFinalPathPartOfUrl($url) {
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $paths = explode('/', $path);
    return end($paths);
}
```

Comment: this is the first i've seen end(), thanks.  i like how i keep learning these new little functions in PHP

Answer (score 1):

```
/(.+?)$
```

That should do...

Comment: Any character, non greedy? That almost seems redundant. Shouldn't it be: /\/(\w+)$/ (maybe not \w depending on what they're looking for though)

Comment: There are lots of characters used in urls, take '%' and '-' for example.

As for the escaping, I presumed the OP would do that themselves...

Comment: No, take as an example, I have no idea what you are going to do with a % in this context :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match ('/\/([a-z])+$/', $url, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

This gets any alphabetic characters trailing the final forward slash, anchored ad the end of the string. If you want to include digits or other characters, add them between the `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need Regex and there aren't any files or queries, use:

```
$dir = array_pop(explode("/", "http://www.ccc.com/hh/jj/kk/ll"));
```